# Rails - Anyone can add an item. Not good

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I prevent just anyone from submitting a form? Right now, any user can update a form on any other user's profiles, where they should only be able to touch theirs.

Should I just hide the form if it's not on the current user's profile, or do something more secure inside the controller?

For instance, I have a form to create a new book. In reality, the only time the form should be displayed is on the logged in user's profile page. The form should be hidden on other's profile pages.

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => "f" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :author, :placeholder => "Author" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add Book', :value => "" %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

I started to use CanCan, but still can't restrict access of creating books on other users' profiles.

My new Ability.rb:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        can :read, :all
        can :create, Book
    end
end
```

**Before filter in application controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :current_user

  def current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Your current_user method would result in an infinite loop, would it not?  Assuming you're using some sort of authentication like `AuthLogic` you'd have to use a different name, like `set_current_user`

Comment: @bdares I'm using Devise, sorry should have mentioned that. It probably has predefined names huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an authorization scheme.  The controller logic is the important part (actually allowing or disallowing the action), but the view is what the user sees, so you should implement both.

While you can roll your own, [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a relatively painless way of doing it.

CanCan makes it easy to implement view logic (you'll still have to do it), like this:

```
<% if can? :create, Book %>
<%= render '/books/form'%>
<% end %>
```

The gem creator, Ryan Bates, is also the creator of RailsCasts.  Conveniently, there is one that [covers CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

For your use case, I'd define an ability like this:

```
can :create, Book do |book|
  book.user = User.current
end
```

You'd need to add a before_filter in the Application Controller to place the current user into the `User.current` variable for this to work (accessing the current user in a model).  And add these two methods to your `User` model:

```
  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end
  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end
```

Comment: Checking out CanCan now! Does it handle the view logic, like hiding the form, too?

Comment: That's exactly what I have (<% if can? :create, Book %>), but it still allows me to create books on other people's accounts...

Comment: Ryan's screencast doesn't really cover how to block the *creating* of comments (in his case) on another user's (post in his case) though.

Comment: You're really helping me out here, thanks! So the before filter would be something like this? 
```class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :current_user
  protect_from_forgery
  
  def current_user
   User.current = current_user
  end
end```

Comment: Sorry that was hard to read. I updated my question w/ the before filter that I currently have

Comment: Okay so after adding that code to the ```User```model, is my before filter correct (see in my question), or not? I'm guessing it's way off :/

Answer (score 2):

Hide the form, and remove user_id as a field. In the controller if user has many/one book(s) then take advantage of that association:

```
def create
   @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])
   ...
end
```

If for some reason the form was accidentally shown the current user would only be able to add their own books.